# Custom Validation in MVC asp.net in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, unobtrusive-validation

I added a custom validation and added an attribute on following class

Class

```
public class Transfer
{
 [MoneyTransfer]
  public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

View Model

```
public Transfer Transfer{ get; set; }
public decimal TransferBalance { get; set; }
public decimal TotalMoney{ get; set; }
```

Validation Class

```
 public class MoneyTransfer: ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
         \\Do Validation
        }
   }
```

Value is passed in as 0 and validationContext and Transfer model but no data

CSHTML Page

```
@model DatabaseMVCPractice.ViewModels.TransfersViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Transfers", FormMethod.Post))
{
 <div class="form-group">        
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Transfer.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Transfer.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>
}
```

The issue is that Validation class does not have any data when I hit submit on the form. If I change the form to use just Transfer model instead of view model, it works fine and Validation Class has correct data. Can I use customer validation for view models?

Comment: Customer or custom?

Comment: @ScottHannen Thank you, Updated

Comment: Have you tried the custom attribute on the ViewModel properties... it's usually a ModelState.IsValid check in the controller that returns errors to the view.

Comment: When you have the custom [MoneyTransfer] attribute in the ViewModel, what does that look like?